# Magento:- Add Grid in Admin Form

Tags: magento

Iam generating a form in Magento Adminhtml.
I have two list boxes Category and SubCategory which are populated cascadingly.
Now after click or change event of subcategory list i want to display magento grid(grid with paging filtering) JUST below that subcategory list.

I dont know which block to  use to show that grid.

Help appreciated.
-Thanks
Hemant

Answer (score 6):

Try to look in Mage files , `magento` already using grid into form, 
look in this file :  `core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Category/Tap/Product.php`
**Product.php is a grid** , to check the result from back-office, check `catalog->manage categories` then click on category products tab

Answer (score -1):

There are many tutorials on creating a grid.
Maybe this one will help?
http://www.webspeaks.in/2010/08/create-admin-backend-module-in-magento.html

Comment: Thanks for the link. But this not what i want. I want to show grid on Form. This link makes me create new tab and does not allow me place grid on Form.

Comment: That appears to be a decent tutorial, however, that page is loading in porn content and is not suitable for posting here.

Comment: Chrome was bugging out about third-party cookies, and there was definitely an inappropriate domain name associated with that cookie.